# WMI query returns hard drive temperature as 0, how to solve this?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, temperature

I'm having trouble getting the right temperature out of a certain hard drive on my application using a WMI query, somehow one of my two hard drives gets 0 back as temperature, while the other one returns a regular temperature such as 34 degrees celsius.

This is my method:

```
public static void GetTemps()
    {
        const byte TEMPERATURE_ATTRIBUTE = 194; 
        try
        {
            int counter = 1;
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                byte[] arrVendorSpecific = (byte[])queryObj["VendorSpecific"];
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("DRIVE: " + (counter + ("=" + arrVendorSpecific[TEMPERATURE_ATTRIBUTE + 5])));
                counter++;
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException err)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(("An error has occurred: " + err.Message));
        }
```

Perhaps the oddest part, is that this code used to work not long ago, although it would still show up a 0 every now and then.

Comment: Maybe the temperature *is* zero.

Comment: Well I have also used other tools, such as Open Hardware Monitor, and they do report actual believable temps.

Comment: what's the `+ 5` for in `arrVendorSpecific`?

Comment: You might be looking at the wrong value, maybe do something that might cause your hard drive to get warmer like running windirstat and iterating over each byte value in `arrVendorSpecific`, and while you do that, check to see which values are changing in your byte array. I tried it, but my SSD only seems to be reporting 50C consistently on this laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use C# To read extended smart data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663980/how-can-i-use-c-sharp-to-read-extended-smart-data)