# S.M.A.R.T SSD info C#

Tags: c#, solid-state-drive

I need to build in a call in my app to check SSD health status.
I've tried multiple examples from different sources but cannot get anything to work.  In all examples I've tried I get the "Not supported" exception in `ManagementObjectSearcher`query or `foreach (ManagementObject data in searcher.Get())` loop

All the examples I've found are pretty outdated so did anything change?  I'm running Windows 10 with .NET 4.6.2.  You'd think there would be a "modern" call to access SMART data.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? Like a single method that is supposed to do this?

Comment: You may take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894138/2793683

Comment: Here's one example that crashes right away http://vasters.com/archive/Reading-ATAPI-SMART-Data-From-Drives-Using-NET-Temperature-Anyone.html

Comment: @ dmoore1181 yes, I tried that one and it crashes in this loop with "Not supported": `// check if SMART reports the drive is failing
...
                foreach (ManagementObject drive in searcher.Get())
                {
                    dicDrives[iDriveIndex].IsOK = (bool)drive.Properties["PredictFailure"].Value == false;
                    iDriveIndex++;
                }`

Comment: By the way, the example that dmoore1181 provided is supposedly designed similar to Crystal Disk tool and yet this tool works flawlessly on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out something was blocking this code on my dev computer.  Even powerShell script returned the same error.  I ran it on the production machines and it works as expected.  Didn't get to the bottom of this on my dev PC but this is secondary.